# Authentication credentials missing error when trying to get a twitter timeline using twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to retrieve the tweets from a twitter users timeline using the Twitter4j library and integrate them into an android app. I have gone through all the specific steps to get my consumer keys/access tokens and have then set them in my code in the following way.

```
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_SECRET)
                .setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true);

        Configuration config = cb.build();
        tf = new TwitterFactory(config);
        twitter = tf.getInstance();

        bearerToken = twitter.getOAuth2Token();

        twitter.setOAuth2Token(bearerToken);;

        // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
        twitter = tf.getSingleton();
        statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(name);
```

However when I run the application, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing. See   http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for details
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.ensureAuthorizationEnabled(TwitterBaseImpl.java:186)
        at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1554)
        at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getUserTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:129)
        at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getUserTimeline(TwitterImpl.java:150)
```

Note: I have searched through numerous similar questions on here on this topic and have had no success thus far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys!